# How to create a function in C to initialize a linked list with a dummy node

Tags: c, function, pointers, linked-list

I'm trying to write a function `generate_list` which will generate a list with one node initialized to with `val` as `0` and `next` as `NULL`. `generate_list` should not take any arguments.

Here are the requirements:

> define a `struct` datatype named `node` which contains an integer number and a pointer to the next node of the list.
>
> define a new datatype named `list`, defined as a pointer to the node. `list` represents the list's head.
>
> define a function of type `list` called `generate_list` which takes no parameters and returns a `list` with a dummy node (integer number = `0`, pointer = `NULL`).

I tried something like this:

```
typedef struct list_node {
   int val;
   struct list_node *next;
}

typedef struct a_list {
   node *head;
}

list generate_list() {
    list *l = malloc(sizeof(*l));
    node d_node;
    l->head = &d_node;
    d_node.val = 0;
    d_node.next = NULL;
    return *l;
}
```

I am not sure if I did correctly the second part and how could I implement the function?

what should I return from it?

Comment: Your question _"How do I initialize my_list?"_ is answered in detail by requirement #3. Please describe more clearly what problem you are having with this.

Comment: "*How can I solve this exercise*". Read your notes. Do more research if need. Write the code. Nobody is just going to do all your homework for you as it really doesn't benefit you in the long run. Please make an attempt, show it and ask a more specific question about one thing that will help you progress. [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) and [How to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0):

you actually did pretty well. But, you must return a pointer to the list from your generate_list function.

It should be like this:

```
a_list *generate_list(void)
{
    a_list *list = (a_list *)malloc(sizeof(a_list));
    list_node *head_node = (list_node *)malloc(sizeof(list_node);
    
    list->head = head_node;
    
    head_node->val = 0;
    head_node->next = NULL;
    
    return list;
}
```

now you want to generate your list inside the function. but, you also want to return an accessible list. Hence, you must malloc it all (the list and the node) so it wouldn't be a local variable (allocated on the stack and disappear after the function returns).

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your code:

- you should include `<stdlib.h>`
- the type definitions must include the type name and end with a `;`
- the argument list of `generate_list` should be defined as `(void)`, not `()` which has a different meaning in C (unlike C++).
- the first node should be allocated, not an automatic variable that will become invalid as soon as the function returns.
- the list itself should not be allocated, but returned by value, a peculiar requirement that is explicit in the problem specification.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node *next;
} node;

typedef struct list {
    node *head;
} list;

list generate_list(void) {
    list l;
    l.head = malloc(sizeof(*n));
    if (l.head == NULL) {
        /* abort with an error message */
        perror("generate_list");
        exit(1);
    }
    l.head->val = 0;
    l.head->next = NULL;
    return l;
}
```